# Access MVT attributes in QGIS' expression builder

Tags: qgis-3, mapbox-vector-tile

I have an MVT layer, where each feature has a "color_index" attribute. I see the attribute when I click a feature and view its info window:

[image: Identify Results window]

...so presumably these attributes are accessible in some way when building queries and rules. In the Expression String Builder, I would expect these attributes to show up under "Fields and Values," but all that's there is "NULL." I've tried `attribute($currentFeature, 'color_index')` without success. Is there a way to access feature attributes?